# Why is loading data from SQL much slower than excel?

Tags: ssas, ssas-tabular

I have a simple tabular model created in SSDT, which I have deployed to my local SSAS instance (compatibility model = *Azure Analysis Services / SQL Server 2017 (1400)*)

Below my two test sources, one from a local SQL 2017 server and one from a local Excel file. Both sources have only one table, with 4 rows each.

```
"dataSources": [
      {
        "type": "structured",
        "name": "SQL/localhost;MyDB",
        "connectionDetails": {
          "protocol": "tds",
          "address": {
            "server": "localhost",
            "database": "MyDB"
          },
          "authentication": null,
          "query": null
        },
        "credential": {
          "AuthenticationKind": "UsernamePassword",
          "kind": "SQL",
          "path": "localhost;MyDB",
          "Username": "MyUserName",
          "EncryptConnection": false
        }
      },
      {
        "type": "structured",
        "name": "FileExcel",
        "connectionDetails": {
          "protocol": "file",
          "address": {
            "path": "C:\\testExcelForSSAS.xlsx"
          },
          "authentication": null,
          "query": null
        },
        "credential": {
          "AuthenticationKind": "Windows",
          "kind": "File",
          "path": "c:\\testexcelforssas.xlsx",
          "Username": "MyUserName"
        },
        "contextExpression": [
          "let",
          "    #\"0001\" = Excel.Workbook(..., null, true)",
          "in",
          "    #\"0001\""
        ]
      }
    ],
```

The problem: (full) processing the excel table source takes less than 1 second, 
(full) processing the SQL table takes up to 20 seconds.

I did a SQL Trace, and this query (in the ExecuteSQL EventSubClass) takes 20 seconds:

```
let __AS_Query__ =  let
    Source = #"SQL/localhost;MyDB",
    dbo_formulas = Source{[Schema="dbo",Item="formulas"]}[Data],
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(dbo_formulas, "NameWithID", each [NameEU] & " (" & Number.ToText([ID])) in
    #"Added Custom" , __AS_Table__ = Table.FromValue(__AS_Query__) in Table.RemoveColumns(__AS_Table__, Table.ColumnsOfType(__AS_Table__, { type table, type record, type list }))
```

For reference, this is the call to the Excel data

```
let __AS_Query__ = 
let
    Source = #"FileExcel",
    Table1_Table = Source{[Item="Table1",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    Table1_Table
, __AS_Table__ = Table.FromValue(__AS_Query__)
in
Table.RemoveColumns(__AS_Table__, Table.ColumnsOfType(__AS_Table__, { type table, type record, type list }))
```

Why does a simple query to fetch 4 rows from SQL takes 20 seconds, while the same amount of data from Excel takes less than a second?

EDIT:
I have done a trace on the SQL server, below the result. The real SQL query (highlighted) takes almost no time, but some other queries before that are taking quite long. Is this due to some configuration of the SSAS connection to this SQL server?

[image: SQL Server Trace]

Thanks

Comment: After some more reading I think it has something to do with Pooling, but I cannot find a way to configure that for the connection in the SSAS model...